# How to create a dynamic string in Swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift

What I want to know is how to create in swift a string with notation on localizable file and replace this notation just before.

```
"welcome" = "Hello %@, Welcome!"
"seeYou"  = "Goodbye %@"
"update"  = "All your profile data was update, %@"
```

in another file:

```
func showMessage(name : String){
  print(welcome,name)
}
```

thanks for the help,

Filipe

Comment: let *name = "Filipe"
var welcome = "Hello \ (name), Welcome!"

print("result is :\ (welcome )")

Comment: this is not exactly a duplicate of the answer mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's much easier in Swift than in Objective-C by using String Interpolation

```
let name = "Filipe"
print("Hello \(name), Welcome!")
```

or the plus operator

```
print("Hello " + name + ", Welcome!")
```

In an environment to process localizable strings use

```
let welcome = "Hello %@, Welcome!"

func showMessage(name : String){
  print(String(format: NSLocalizedString(welcome, comment: ""), name))
}

showMessage("Filipe")
```

Comment: `print`also supports this now: `print("Hello", name, ", Welcome!")` String doesn't :(

Comment: Yes, but you'll get an unwanted space character after the `name` variable in this example.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
func showMessage(name : String) {
    let msg : String = String(format: "Hello %@, Welcome!", name)
    print(msg)
}
```

Check [this link](https://thatthinginswift.com/string-formatting/).